# expand Ext JS GridPanel column width

Tags: javascript, extjs

I using Ext JS 2.3.0 and have a GridPanel that looks like this:

[image]

I want to expand the width of the column such that the scroll bar is pushed over the extreme right of the panel, thus eliminating the empty space to the right of the scroll bar.

The relevant code is shown below:

```
    var colModel = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
        {
            id: 'name',
            header: locale['dialogSearch.column.name'],
            sortable: true,
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }
    ]);

    var selModel = new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({singleSelect: false});

    this._searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        title: locale['dialogSearch.results.name'],
        height: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'name',
        store: this._searchResultsStore,
        view: new Ext.grid.GridView(),
        colModel: colModel,
        selModel: selModel,
        hidden: true,
        buttonAlign: 'center',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: locale["dialogSearch.button.add"],
                width: 50,
                handler: function () {
                }
            },
            {
                text: locale["dialogSearch.button.cancel"],
                width: 50,
                handler: function () {
                    entitySearchWindow.close();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the forceFit config for the grid view:

```
this._searchResultsPanel = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        title: locale['dialogSearch.results.name'],
        height: 400,
        layout: 'fit',
        viewConfig: {
          forceFit: true
        }, ....
```

I'm not sure if this isn't redundant so you can remove this part `view: new Ext.grid.GridView(),`

Comment: I don't have `view: new Ext.grid.GridView()` anywhere in my code

Comment: well you have in the config of the grid above. Instead of that you can just put the viewConfig as presented above

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the column but the grid itself which does not stretch to fill the window body completely.

Put the `layout: 'fit'` property onto the window config instead of onto the grid config (where it needs to be removed). You should also remove the `height` property because the grid height will determined by the window's size.

Comment: My first thought was the same, but if you look at the code, the grid actualy containes the buttons and title, so the grid is actualy the correct size, is the columns that are the problem

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `layout` and `height` properties?

Comment: Do you add the grid after the window has been rendered? If so, do a `win.doLayout()` after adding the component.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
    flex: 1,
```

to one of the the columns config